# SparkSql - Junit: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, junit4

I am trying to test sparksql in junit.  Unfortunately I am using a hive udf (percentiles) so I need a hive-context.

Everything works fine for one test, but if I run two tests the second test fails:

```
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database
```

I'm closing the spark context after each test but that doesn't seem to have any effect on the HiveContext.  And I do not know how I can close the HiveContext.